# Как запретить срабатывание события на дочернем элементе?

Tags: javascript, события

Есть два вложенных блока `div`, с идентификаторами `a` и `b`.

```
<div id="a">
   <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Оба блока имеют события `click`, которое выводит что-то в консоль.

```
b.onclick = function(){ console.log('clicked "b"') }
a.onclick = function(){ console.log('clicked "a"') }
```

Требуется, не меняя обработчик `onclick` для блока `b`, выполнить только событие родительского элемента `a`. (без jquery)

---

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: то есть при клике на `b` вы хотите что бы его обработчик не срабатывал?

Comment: @Grundy Да, все верно. То есть размеры у них 100% на 100%.

Comment: почему тогда просто не отписать онклик от `b`?

Comment: К сожалению оно еще потребуется. Это событие ставит плагин, где-то глубоко в созданном объекте. То есть пересоздать его я не смогу.

Comment: стоит подробнее описать с чем именно вы боретесь. а так же можно почитать про всплытие событий и реализацию его в разных браузерах.

Comment: Согласен, но всплытие работает от event.target. А родительский блок, как раз самый последний в цепочке получается...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36396/discussion-between-grundy-and-mike).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё достаточно тривиально. Есть события, которые всплывают вверх по DOM, есть которые нисходят по DOM. Это т.н. Bubling и Capturing. Об этом подробно почитать можно [здесь](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/intro#poryadok-srabatyvaniya-sobytiy). Соответственно модифицируем код так, чтобы можно было использовать Capturing. Тогда сначала мы попадем в более верхний обработчик, соответственно в обработчик `a`. И всё что остается сделать - остановить ход события. Это делается при помощи `event.stopPropagation();`

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');

b.onclick = function(){ alert('clicked "b"') }
a.addEventListener("click", function(e){
 alert('clicked a');
  
  e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

```css
html, body, div {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#a {background-color: #333}
#b {background-color: #bbb}
```

```html
<div id="a">
   <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Жаль что Capturing не поддерживается в IE. Спасибо за ответ!